# JAVA Files and graphing streaming data?

Tags: java, linux, file, graph

Im working with linux servers and I am to suppose to develope a program that will graph cpu usage, memory ussage, process and user defined metrics. So far they told me I could start by reading streaming data from a .txt file. I looked at jfreechart, jconsole but i dont think they work so I found LiveGraph. Problem I am having is that it is not graphing everytime data is written to it. Im using a thread sleeper and filewriter object to write to the file every 10 seconds. Has anybody used this tool or has a better solution for what Im looking for? Thank you would be of great help. I generate data every 10 seconds to the file but LiveGraph only graphs it at the end when the file closes and i need it to graph and stay open.

Answer (score 1):

There are **plenty** of server monitoring tools out there, both free and commercial. You can start by looking for some [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html) or [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20server%20monitoring).

But of course, using an already made software removes the excitement of hacking your own. :)

Comment: Yeah at my work they dont want me to implement those programs